# Recyclerview notifyItemRemoved removes a wrong item and not working properly when using view binding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview

When removing an item from recycler view, it is not working properly. For instance, if you remove beginning from the start it removes other items that are not pressed or it won't remove some of them even if you pressed it

**Activity Class**

```
List<ModelPlayers> modelPlayers = new ArrayList<>();

modelPlayers.add(new ModelPlayer(R.drawable.photo_ronaldo,"Ronaldo"));
modelPlayers.add(new ModelPlayer(R.drawable.photo_messi,"Messi"));
modelPlayers.add(new ModelPlayer(R.drawable.photo_neymar,"Neymar"));
modelPlayers.add(new ModelPlayer(R.drawable.photo_mbappe,"Mbappe"));
modelPlayers.add(new ModelPlayer(R.drawable.photo_ramos,"Ramos"));

LinearLayoutManager llm= new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

AdapterPlay adapterPlay= new AdapterPlay(activity, modelPlayers);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPlay);
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class AdapterPlay extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPlay.PlayerViewHolder> {

    public static class PlayerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        PlayerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    private Activity mActivity;
    private List<ModelPlayers> modelPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
    private ItemPlayBinding mBinding;

    public AdapterPlay(Activity activity, List<ModelPlayers> modelPlayers) {
        this.mActivity=activity;
        this.modelPlayers = modelPlayers;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public PlayerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        mBinding= ItemPlayBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mActivity),viewGroup,false);
        return new PlayerViewHolder(mBinding.getRoot());
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlayerViewHolder PlayerViewHolder, int i) {
        ModelPlayers modelPlayer = this.modelPlayers.get(i);
        mBinding.mainImage.setImageResource(modelPlayer.getImage());
        mBinding.mainText.setText(modelPlayer.getTitle());

        mBinding.mainText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                modelPlayers.remove(i);
                notifyItemRemoved(i);
//                notifyItemRangeChanged(i,modelPlays.size());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  modelPlayers.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not capture item position you get during `onBindViewHolder` - your click listener should refer to `viewholder.getBindingAdapterPosition()` instead.

Comment: sorry, this didn't solve it either

Comment: Use holder.getLayoutPosition() from your onBindViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the problem existed because of improper usage of view binding in adapter class.

The changes is only made from the adapter class.

```
public class AdapterPlay extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPlay.PlayerViewHolder> {

    public static class PlayerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //made changes here, placing the binding here in the viewholder
        private ItemPlayBinding mBinding;
        PlayerViewHolder(ItemPlayBinding binding){
            super(binding.getRoot());
            mBinding = binding;
        }
    }

    private Activity mActivity;
    private List<ModelPlayer> modelPlayers = new ArrayList<>();

    public AdapterPlay(Activity activity, List<ModelPlayer> modelPlayers) {
        this.mActivity=activity;
        this.modelPlayers = modelPlayers;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public PlayerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        //made changes here
        return new PlayerViewHolder(ItemPlayBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(mActivity),viewGroup,false));
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlayerViewHolder playerViewHolder, int i) {
        ModelPlayer modelPlayer = this.modelPlayers.get(i);
        //instead of the first mbinding.view I know make it viewholder.mbinding.view
        playerViewHolder.mBinding.mainImage.setImageResource(modelPlayer.getImage());
        playerViewHolder.mBinding.mainText.setText(modelPlayer.getTitle());
        playerViewHolder.mBinding.mainText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                modelPlayers.remove(i);
                notifyItemRemoved(i);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(i,getItemCount());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  modelPlayers.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **holder.getLayoutPosition()** and not **position**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NotificationAdapter.MyHolderView holder, int position) {
    MyModel model = arraylist.get(position);
        holder.delete_imgview.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            anInterface.deleteItem(model, holder.getLayoutPosition());
            notifyItemRemoved(holder.getLayoutPosition());
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Man, i had the same problem!
Creating the binding inside the ViewHolder like this:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ItemProductResumeBinding binding;
    public MyViewHolder(ItemProductResumeBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }
}
```

and inflating it like this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ProductsAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ProductsAdapter.MyViewHolder(ItemProductResumeBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
}
```

solved the problem. Thanks! Saved my day!

Comment: I assume that what you are saying thanks for is the only other existing answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69458585/7733418 . Correct? Or are you trying to provide your own solution, which is different from those already shown here and which provides an additional insight? In that case you probably want to [edit] and rephrase, in oprder to avoid the misconcept that you are only saying thanks....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).